# Return from the parent process code or common code

Tags: c, linux, child-process

In this program, the parent process creates a child process, then the child executes `ls -l`. The parent process waits for the child process to complete and then returns using `return 0;`.

```
/*child's output redirected to file*/
/*sps, 6262015*/

/*Headers*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

/*Start*/
int main(void)
{
    //Create a child process
    int ret = fork();
    if(ret<0)
            exit(1);
    /*Child code*/
    else if(ret==0)
    {
            char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};

            //Execute 'ls -l'
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }
    /*Parent code*/
    else if(ret>0)
    {
            int status;
            int w = waitpid(ret, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    }
    /*Where to place this ???*/
    return 0;
}
```

Although above code works correctly, I am not sure where to place the `return 0;` statement. For instance, in the above code it is at the end so it is common to both the parent and child processes.

But in this program, the child process calls `execvp`, so it will never reach the last line of the code which has `return 0;`. So, taking this into account, can I place the `return 0;` inside the parent code as below?

```
 /*Parent code*/
 else if(ret>0)
 {
         int status;
         int w = waitpid(ret, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
         return 0;
 }
```

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to putting the `return 0;` statement inside the parent process code?

Answer (score 2):

As for all these functions:  Take a look at the `man` page.  It states
that `execvp` (respectively `execve`) will return on error with return
value `-1` and with `errno` set.

Since you are already handling such errors with `fork` you might as
well do it here and either `exit(1)`, or fall through to the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*child's output redirected to file*/
/*sps, 6262015*/
```

I don't know what this comment is. All other comments in the file are completely useless as they state the obvious.

```
/*Headers*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
```

`sys/` headers should go first. The order you include these two is incorrect, which you can check with the manpage.

```
/*Start*/
int main(void)
{
    //Create a child process
```

This useless comment does not match the style of previous useless comments.

```
    int ret = fork();
    if(ret<0)
```

Consider adding spaces: `ret < 0`

```
            exit(1);
```

This should state the error with e.g. [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror).

```
    /*Child code*/
    else if(ret==0)
    {
            char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
```

It is a standard idiom to name `main`'s argument array as `argv`, so this is a terrible abuse of the name.

```
            //Execute 'ls -l'
```

Not only useless, but actively harmful comment waiting to get out of sync with the content of the table.

```
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }
    /*Parent code*/
    else if(ret>0)
```

By this time `ret` has to be > 0, so this can be a mere `else`.

```
    {
            int status;
            int w = waitpid(ret, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
```

Incorrect. `waitpid` can return prematurely due to an error, which is unchecked.

```
    }
    /*Where to place this ???*/
    return 0;
```

The question arises in the first place because the code looks incorrect. The child should `_Exit` with an error if `execvp` fails, which alone makes this question obsolete. Another thing to note is error handling in the parent process - don't you want to note somehow that `ls` failed?

I assume this is not a standalone tool in its entirety, if it is, it makes no sense whatsoever, as in the worst case it should exec `ls -l` directly, but preferably whatever executes it would do `ls -l` on its own (and that is assuming execing `ls -l` even makes sense).

```
}
```

Comment: The first comment is his username plus a timestamp, but yeah, not useful. Could you add a reference for the order of includes?